# Initialize array with size and default value

Tags: arrays, groovy

I'm looking for the best way to initialize an array by specifying its size and a default value (here the default value will be "").

For example if i've got :

```
def myTab = ["","","","","","","","",""]
```

How can i initialize this same array without writing each field, only by changing the size and/or default value ?

Something like

```
def myTab = new String[9] //(combined with a 'withDefault' method equivalent)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
def myTab = [""] * 9
```

Btw, that's a list, not an array

If you really need an array (which you probably don't), you can do

```
String[] myTab = [""] * 9
```

Comment: Thank you, the list will definitely be fine